# Joomla - one function for frontend and backend

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I have made Joomla component with frontend and backend (admin). Now I need to call a function in frontend controller from backend controller. Duplicating this function is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible and is done with some components (such as K2 for example) - they write the include to the administrator file.

When they're including a function they simply include the document from administrator/component/com_whatever/etc/file.php  - that allows them to use any functions from the administrator backend in their front end process' without having to duplicate the functions.